# innerHTML doesn't work correctly with xhtml in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, xhtml, innerhtml

I've got a trouble with Chrome5.0.375.70, **but FF** 3.6.3 and **Opera** 10.53 are OK. Below is the line of code:

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

The **data** object from the code is a document (typeof(data) == 'object') and I've got it by ajax request to **chapter01.xhtml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html [
<!ENTITY D "&#x2014;">
<!ENTITY o "&#x2018;">
<!ENTITY c "&#x2019;">
<!ENTITY O "&#x201C;">
<!ENTITY C "&#x201D;">
]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Alice's Adventures in Wonderland by Lewis Carroll. Chapter I: Down the Rabbit-Hole</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="application/vnd.adobe-page-template+xml" href="page-template.xpgt"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="title_box">
<h2 class="chapnum">Chapter I</h2>
<h2 class="chaptitle">Down the Rabbit-Hole</h2>
<hr/>
</div>
```

The Chrome **cuts** all **before body** and **as a result** link to **css** in header **is missed**; user can't see formatted text and images.

How can I fix it or bypass?

P.S. I try to put **chapter01.xhtml** into div which is contained by `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: You're using an HTML5 doctype, but you say it's XHTML. Are you really trying to stick a complete `<html>...</html>` body into the middle of another document?  If you check your XHTML DTD, you'll find that you can't do that ...

Comment: I try to put that **chapter01.xhtml** into div which is contained by <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">. 
Where can I check the info you have pointed me out? (Because I am weak at it)

Comment: are you trying to "nest" HTML documents like this: `<html><body><div><html><body></body></html></div></body></html>`? Because thats not allowed

Comment: Yep. The problem is that it works in FF and Opera. Where/How to check the restriction?

Comment: It isn't so much a restriction as different levels of being able to recover from errors. Don't make the error in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHTHML` is **NON STANDARD** and is a bad practice and is browser implementation dependent and should not be used. Especially with XHTML it isn't supported.

Comment: @lark - that section is specific to HTML which proves @fuzzy's point.

Comment: Correct, it is "standardized" whatever that means within the w3c on HTML.  I am just confused as to why innerHTML should be avoided.  jQuery the popular framework you may have heard of, uses it quite extensively.  Granted there is a time and place for anything in the web, discouraging the use of innerHTML is foreign to me.

Comment: Just because jQuery uses something doesn't automatically make it a good idea.

Comment: if you are going to do XHTML, innerHTML is an especially bad practice, like most shortcuts, it is a hacky short sighted propertiery thing that everyone in a fit of bad judgement decided to support.

Comment: Do either of you care to elaborate on your replies.  Tim, granted not *everything* jQuery does is a good idea, it obviously has bugs... but do you care to extend on any possible bugs that could incur with the use of it?  Same fuzzy, you claim its a short sighted proprietary thing, but yet you have nothing to back up your claims that it is a bad idea to use.  In most cases its the only performant way to load in external content.

Comment: just google it, even in the link you posted has lots of limitations, like it doesn't execute script tags, it __ONLY__ works as HTML, just the fact that it has all those rules for parsing and failures and side effects just SCREAMS crap. The fact that the browsers all implement it differently, I could go on, but google does a great job of that. If you are happy with using it and the buggy cross platform limitations to just HTML the go for it. I don't have time for that kind of drama. The __single__ that this question is being asked is enough of a reason to make it a bad practice.

Comment: And "faster" isn't a good argument, since the times for something like this are measured in at most double digit milliseconds differences.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I wanted to filter DOM elements and the best way I found was to use a mix of DOMParser and XmlSerializer found here:

http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/convert-xml-document-to-string-in-javascript

This is a reasonable cross browser method.

Edit: To elaborate a bit more, you would load in the html string to the DOMParser and be able to work with the DOMDocument as you normally would, then you could use XmlSerializer or the IE equivalent to pump out the new markup.

Comment: Actually I have 2 types of data objects: first is the document and second is a string (like "<html><body><div></div></body></html>"). The second one I handled by a trick (jQuery): var hiddendiv = $('<div/>'); hiddendiv.html(data); $('#content').html(hiddendiv.html());   The trick works good, but the first (document) is a bit uncontrollable.

Comment: If you set that content in a div you will have nothing but issues.  Since "most" browser implementations will strip out <body>, <html> and <head> tags.  I would recommended using a DOMDocument like I suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems a bit complicated, but I will investigate the idea.